# Set row height of gridview in webform when in edit mode

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that I need to use to edit and update a table in SQL.  I have the gridview, the edit, update and cancel functionality all set.  My problem is that when the user selects the edit function, the row height drops to a single line.  Unfortunately, the cells that need to be updated are comment fields so there can be more than one line of information.  What I would like to do is change the edit mode to resize the row height so the user can see the entire cell contents.  I have tried the DataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode but this only applies to a windows form not a webform.

I am using Visual Web Developer, SQL2008R2 and asp.net

Answer (score 0):

In the GridView_RowDataBound you can check the row being edited and set it's height:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowIndex == GridView1.EditIndex)
      {

           e.Row.Height = 340;
      }
 }
```

Assuming that you have something like this in RowEditing:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindGridView();
}
```